# Load file based on line number in sqlldr

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am trying to load header and detail records from a file. The only way I know the difference between the header and the detail records is the line number. The first line is always the header and the other lines are detail records.

How can I specify the line number of a file when doing a conditional load? I would like to do something like:

```
LOAD DATA 
APPEND INTO TABLE x
WHEN [line_number] = 1
([mapping for header line])
WHEN [line_number] > 1
([mapping for detail lines])
```

The only reason I ask is b/c I take the primary key from the header record in the database and insert it into each detail record. That is a sequence that doesn't get populated until the insert into the header table. I have to load the header/detail in the same transaction because I can't call currval on the sequence until I call nextval - which is only called in the header insert.

Is there a way for me to do this?

Comment: Do you actually need to do something with the header? Does the data load depend on what you did with the headeR?

Comment: No the load doesn't depend on what I do with the header, I just need different mappings for the header and detail but in the same control file

Comment: You'll probably need two control files then, one for the header (I think there's a LINES option to limit number of lines processed), then Phil's SKIP option for the data load.

Comment: Right, I did have 2 control files. The header had: OPTIONS(direct=false, LOAD=1) for the header line and the detail control file had: OPTIONS(direct=false, SKIP=1) 

The problem is, I need a sequence that populates the primary key in the header table to be used in the detail table (so I can map header to details). I call the sequence.NextVal when loading the header but I can't call sequence.CurrVal when I load the details b/c I'm in a separate sqlldr session...that's why I'm aiming to load both the header/detail in one control file

Comment: Ah, I see. No idea if that's doable. You should edit those details into the question, that's rather important information.

Comment: Looks like the best thing for you to do is use an external table, rather than sqlldr, and make use of `RECNUM`

Answer (score 1):

`skip=N` is what you're looking for. Skips the first N rows, so in your case you just want to skip the first.

```
OPTIONS(skip=1)
LOAD DATA
... rest of normal control file
```

Comment: I tried that, but I don't want to skip the header, I just want to have a different mapping for the header and a different one for the details based on the line number. And in the same control file :\